# Turning on & off thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here's the thing, I have started with C# and I want to do something like this:

I have a Windows Form Application with one button and the picturebox.

Clicking on a button should result in turning property "Running" on true/false, by the actual state. That is done.

Also, it should result into turning on the script that will be doing constantly a job as the program runs. This "job" will be described in Run() method. And I want this method to be executed only when Running == true, in moment it becomes false, the method should end.
So I decided put it into the thread and in the method where I switch between Running = true and Running = false, I try to start the thread and abort it.

Why do I want to do this? Because I want to be able to turn program working on and off by the button I mentioned at the beginning.

This is what I came up with:

```
        Thread thProgram;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thProgram = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Run));
    }

    private bool Running = false;


    public void Run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(this.Running)
        {
            i++;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Terminated");
    }

     // handling bot activation button (changing color of a pictureBox1), switching this.Running property
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Running)
        {
            thProgram.Abort();
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Running = false;
        }
        else
        {
            thProgram.Start();
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            this.Running = true;
        }
    }
```

I can click the button exactly twice, and it appears that everything is all right... but when I click it for the third time, error pops up:

(it highlights the line "thProgram.Start();"

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.
```

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide me with.

Comment: are you looking for a BackgroundWorker() ?

Comment: A Thread object is a single-use object.  Once it stops running, it is no longer of use.  You have to create a new instance.  This is not unusual, your Form behaves the same way.  So you don't want to create the instance in your constructor, you want to do that in your Click event handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is Self-explaining

When you press the button for the first time, the thread starts and falls into its main loop. 
The second button press aborts the thread (which is always a bad idea. That flag you used is enough) and the thread terminates.

The third button press? From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Thread.Start()` :

`Once the thread terminates, it cannot be restarted with another call to Start.`

Answer (score 2):

To freeze a thread without terminating it, I suggest using `AutoResetEvent`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    thProgram = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Run));
}

private bool Running = false;
private AutoResetEvent ThreadHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);


public void Run()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        ThreadHandle.WaitOne();
        i++;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Terminated");
}

 // handling bot activation button (changing color of a pictureBox1), switching this.Running property
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.Running)
    {
        thProgram.Abort();
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.ThreadHandle.Reset();
        this.Running = false;
    }
    else
    {
        thProgram.Start();
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        this.ThreadHandle.Set();
        this.Running = true;
    }
}
```